# Does hand-to-hand favor different SPECIAL attributes than ranged combat, and how?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Fallout Shelter recently added melee / hand-to-hand weapons to the game.

How do SPECIAL stats enhance hand-to-hand attacks as opposed to SPECIAL attributes enhancing ranged weapon (gun) attacks?  Is there a difference, and if so, what is it?

Answer (score 1):

i been playing the game for a decent bit of time and I had a dweller with 4 in strength (who had a baseball bat with 5-15 dmg) and over time he has been in the gym area and i got him to up his strength 2 and the damage hasn't changed so from what i can tell it is the same as a gun in the strength  stat